# Как сделать паузу для canvas анимации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, анимация, canvas

Вот canvas анимация(*код ниже*).
как сделать ,чтобы по нажатию на на кнопку **pause**.
Элементы анимации (*облака*) останавливались на месте ,как бы становясь на паузу.
Спасибо!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
body {
  background:  #F3F6FF;
}
canvas{
  display: block;
}
.button-c{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.pause{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="button-c">click</button>
  <button class="pause">pause</button>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function Particles(){
  //particle colors
  this.colors = [
    '255, 255, 255'
  ]
  //adds gradient to particles on true
  //adds white border
  this.border = false;
  //particle radius min/max
  this.minRadius = 10; 
  this.maxRadius = 50;
  //particle opacity min/max
  this.minOpacity = 1;
  this.maxOpacity = 1;
  //particle speed min/max
  this.minSpeed = .05;
  this.maxSpeed = .5;
  //frames per second 
  this.fps = 60;
  //number of particles
  this.numParticles = 20;
  //required canvas variables
  this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
}

/**
 * Initializes everything
 * @method init
 */
Particles.prototype.init = function(){
  this.render();
  this.createCircle();
}

/**
 * generates random number between min and max values
 * @param  {number} min value
 * @param  {number} max malue
 * @return {number} random number between min and max
 * @method _rand
 */
Particles.prototype._rand = function(min, max){
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

/**
 * Sets canvas size and updates values on resize
 * @method render
 */
 Particles.prototype.render = function(){ 
  var self = this,
      wHeight = $(window).height(),
      wWidth = $(window).width();
  
  self.canvas.width = wWidth;
  self.canvas.height = wHeight;
  
  $(window).on('resize', self.render);
}

/**
 * Randomly creates particle attributes
 * @method createCircle
 */
Particles.prototype.createCircle = function(){
  var particle = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.numParticles; i++) {
    var self = this,
        color = self.colors[~~(self._rand(0, self.colors.length))];
    
    particle[i] = {
      radius    : self._rand(self.minRadius, self.maxRadius),
      xPos      : self._rand(0, canvas.width),
      yPos      : self._rand(0, canvas.height),
      xVelocity : self._rand(self.minSpeed, self.maxSpeed),
      yVelocity : self._rand(self.minSpeed, self.maxSpeed),
      color     : 'rgba(' + color + ',' + self._rand(self.minOpacity, self.maxOpacity) + ')'
    }
    
    //once values are determined, draw particle on canvas
    self.draw(particle, i);
  }
  //...and once drawn, animate the particle
  self.animate(particle);
}

/**
 * Draws particles on canvas
 * @param  {array} Particle array from createCircle method
 * @param  {number} i value from createCircle method
 * @method draw
 */
Particles.prototype.draw = function(particle, i){
  var self = this,
      ctx = self.ctx;
  
  if (self.blurry === true ) {
    //creates gradient if blurry === true
    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(particle[i].xPos, particle[i].yPos, particle[i].radius, particle[i].xPos, particle[i].yPos, particle[i].radius/1.25);
    
    grd.addColorStop(1.000, particle[i].color);
    grd.addColorStop(0.000, 'rgba(34, 34, 34, 0)');
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  } else {
    //otherwise sets to solid color w/ opacity value
    ctx.fillStyle = particle[i].color; 
  }
  
  if (self.border === true) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(particle[i].xPos, particle[i].yPos, particle[i].radius, Math.PI, 0, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

/**
 * Animates particles 
 * @param  {array} particle value from createCircle & draw methods
 * @method animate
 */
Particles.prototype.animate = function(particle){
  var self = this,
          ctx = self.ctx;
  
  setInterval(function(){
    //clears canvas
    self.clearCanvas();
    //then redraws particles in new positions based on velocity
    for (var i = 0; i < self.numParticles; i++) {
      particle[i].xPos += particle[i].xVelocity;
 
     
      //if particle goes off screen call reset method to place it offscreen to the left/bottom
      if (particle[i].xPos > self.canvas.width + particle[i].radius || particle[i].yPos > self.canvas.height + particle[i].radius) {
        self.resetParticle(particle, i);
      } else {
        self.draw(particle, i);
      }
    }  
  }, 1000/self.fps); 
}

/**
 * Resets position of particle when it goes off screen
 * @param  {array} particle value from createCircle & draw methods
 * @param  {number} i value from createCircle method
 * @method resetParticle
 */
Particles.prototype.resetParticle = function(particle, i){
  var self = this;
  
  var random = self._rand(0, 1);
  
  if (random > .5) { 
    // 50% chance particle comes from left side of window...
    particle[i].xPos = -particle[i].radius;
    particle[i].yPos = self._rand(0, canvas.height);
  } else {
    //... or bottom of window
    particle[i].xPos = self._rand(0, canvas.width);
    particle[i].yPos = canvas.height + particle[i].radius;   
  }
  //redraw particle with new values
  self.draw(particle, i);
}

/**
 * Clears canvas between animation frames
 * @method clearCanvas
 */
Particles.prototype.clearCanvas = function(){
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

 
// go go go!
$(".button-c").on("click", function(){
  var particle = new Particles().init(); 
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: ну раз у Вас анимация основана на setInterval - то поможет clearInterval, ну или флаг, по которому Вы поймете что кадр надо пропустить, первый вариант предпочтительнее

Comment: так же можно поставить velocity в 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Particles(){
  this.pause = false;

  //particle colors
  this.colors = [
    '255, 255, 255'
  ]
  //adds gradient to particles on true
  //adds white border
  this.border = false;
  //particle radius min/max
  this.minRadius = 10; 
  this.maxRadius = 50;
  //particle opacity min/max
  this.minOpacity = 1;
  this.maxOpacity = 1;
  //particle speed min/max
  this.minSpeed = .05;
  this.maxSpeed = .5;
  //frames per second 
  this.fps = 60;
  //number of particles
  this.numParticles = 20;
  //required canvas variables
  this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
}

/**
 * Initializes everything
 * @method init
 */
Particles.prototype.init = function(){
  this.render();
  this.createCircle();
}

/**
 * generates random number between min and max values
 * @param  {number} min value
 * @param  {number} max malue
 * @return {number} random number between min and max
 * @method _rand
 */
Particles.prototype._rand = function(min, max){
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

/**
 * Sets canvas size and updates values on resize
 * @method render
 */
 Particles.prototype.render = function(){ 
  var self = this,
      wHeight = $(window).height(),
      wWidth = $(window).width();
  
  self.canvas.width = wWidth;
  self.canvas.height = wHeight;
  
  $(window).on('resize', self.render);
}

/**
 * Randomly creates particle attributes
 * @method createCircle
 */
Particles.prototype.createCircle = function(){
  var particle = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.numParticles; i++) {
    var self = this,
        color = self.colors[~~(self._rand(0, self.colors.length))];
    
    particle[i] = {
      radius    : self._rand(self.minRadius, self.maxRadius),
      xPos      : self._rand(0, canvas.width),
      yPos      : self._rand(0, canvas.height),
      xVelocity : self._rand(self.minSpeed, self.maxSpeed),
      yVelocity : self._rand(self.minSpeed, self.maxSpeed),
      color     : 'rgba(' + color + ',' + self._rand(self.minOpacity, self.maxOpacity) + ')'
    }
    
    //once values are determined, draw particle on canvas
    self.draw(particle, i);
  }
  //...and once drawn, animate the particle
  self.animate(particle);
}

/**
 * Draws particles on canvas
 * @param  {array} Particle array from createCircle method
 * @param  {number} i value from createCircle method
 * @method draw
 */
Particles.prototype.draw = function(particle, i){
  var self = this,
      ctx = self.ctx;
  
  if (self.blurry === true ) {
    //creates gradient if blurry === true
    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(particle[i].xPos, particle[i].yPos, particle[i].radius, particle[i].xPos, particle[i].yPos, particle[i].radius/1.25);
    
    grd.addColorStop(1.000, particle[i].color);
    grd.addColorStop(0.000, 'rgba(34, 34, 34, 0)');
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  } else {
    //otherwise sets to solid color w/ opacity value
    ctx.fillStyle = particle[i].color; 
  }
  
  if (self.border === true) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(particle[i].xPos, particle[i].yPos, particle[i].radius, Math.PI, 0, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

/**
 * Animates particles 
 * @param  {array} particle value from createCircle & draw methods
 * @method animate
 */
Particles.prototype.animate = function(particle){
  var self = this,
          ctx = self.ctx;
  
  setInterval(function(){
    if(self.pause) return;
    //clears canvas
    self.clearCanvas();
    //then redraws particles in new positions based on velocity
    for (var i = 0; i < self.numParticles; i++) {
      particle[i].xPos += particle[i].xVelocity;
 
     
      //if particle goes off screen call reset method to place it offscreen to the left/bottom
      if (particle[i].xPos > self.canvas.width + particle[i].radius || particle[i].yPos > self.canvas.height + particle[i].radius) {
        self.resetParticle(particle, i);
      } else {
        self.draw(particle, i);
      }
    }  
  }, 1000/self.fps); 
}

/**
 * Resets position of particle when it goes off screen
 * @param  {array} particle value from createCircle & draw methods
 * @param  {number} i value from createCircle method
 * @method resetParticle
 */
Particles.prototype.resetParticle = function(particle, i){
  var self = this;
  
  var random = self._rand(0, 1);
  
  if (random > .5) { 
    // 50% chance particle comes from left side of window...
    particle[i].xPos = -particle[i].radius;
    particle[i].yPos = self._rand(0, canvas.height);
  } else {
    //... or bottom of window
    particle[i].xPos = self._rand(0, canvas.width);
    particle[i].yPos = canvas.height + particle[i].radius;   
  }
  //redraw particle with new values
  self.draw(particle, i);
}

/**
 * Clears canvas between animation frames
 * @method clearCanvas
 */
Particles.prototype.clearCanvas = function(){
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

var particle = new Particles();
// go go go!
$(".button-c").on("click", function(){
  particle.init(); 
});

$(".pause").on("click", function(){
  particle.pause = !particle.pause;
});
```

```css
      *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
body {
  background:  #F3F6FF;
}
canvas{
  display: block;
}
.button-c{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.pause{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="button-c">click</button>
  <button class="pause">pause</button>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```